# How to install startup disk creator in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: boot, usb, 19.04

I know I'm supposed to have the Startup Disk Creator installed in the Ubuntu 19.04 version, but I ran the

```
apt policy usb-creator-gtk
```

And got

```
usb-creator-gtk:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3.5
  Version table:
     0.3.5 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
```

What I want to do is boot my other PC with a USB stick, I've already installed the Ubuntu 19.04 on the USB stick, but the PC is not detecting it (it is not in FAT16 format, and I can't figure out how to reformat it).

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu on the USB stick? Please describe the method and tool that you used. What computer is it (brand name and model)? How do you make the computer boot from the USB stick (what actions before/during/after [re]boot?

Comment: (I realize now after researching more that this is stupid) I just downloaded the Ubuntu 19.04 on my laptop, then copied the file to the USB stick. 

I just downloaded the DISKS application and formatted the USB to FAT. I put the USB in the PC I want o boot it with, and even though the PC detects it, I can't seem to be able to boot it with the USB stick.

Comment: You cannot simply copy the iso file (as a file to the file system in the USB drive). It won't make a bootable drive. But the Startup Disk Creator is a good tool for that purpose. Try to install it in your current Ubuntu system, and then use it to create your bootable USB boot drive in order to install Ubuntu into some other computer.

Comment: But I am comfused, because both the Startup Disk Creator and Disks should be installed already in your Ubuntu System (it is part of the standard installation). Do you really have an Ubuntu 19.04 system installed? Or is it something else, for example Ubuntu Server or some minimal installation, or some re-spin (modified by some third party)?

Comment: @sudodus It could be Lubuntu. I'm not sure but I think that LXQT is the default for Lubuntu now instead of LXDE. If LXQT is the default, then the default disk creator would probably be `usb-creator-kde` instead of `usb-creator-gtk`.

Comment: It is actually Kubuntu but I easily managed to install the Startup Disk Creator and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To *install* the application, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk
```

Additionally, if you are running KDE or Kubuntu instead of Ubuntu or Ubuntu Gnome, then you should probably use `usb-creator-kde` instead of `usb-creator-gtk`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install usb-creator-kde
```

Furthermore, if you are using LXQT on Lubuntu, then you probably want to use `usb-creator-kde`.