# Install Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu Mate 20.04

Tags: apt, startup-disk-creator

i am trying to install the Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu Mate (Release 20.04.01 LTS 64bit)

Supposedly it should be pre-installed but I tried with command “usb-creator-gtk” and got the message that it cant be found but installed. I then tried to install trough command “sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk”  This gave me the following error messages:

```
E: Type 'dep' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type 'dep' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I read in an different answer that “sudo apt update” /upgrade should do the trick but this gave me  error messages as well

```
E: Type 'dep' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type 'dep' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

How should I proceed?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello. Remove line 1 in the sources list. It has nothing to do with what you are trying to do but it is what the error is about. Something to do with the brave browser.

Comment: You should be able to install Startup Disk Creator by running `sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk` I honestly don't know if it will work. If it doesn't, check https://ubuntu-mate.org/faq/usb-image/ for a possible solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix this "E: Type '\*' is not known on line \* in source list ..." update error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-e-type-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)

Comment: If SDC is not there for you, you can use Disks to restore the ISO file to a blank USB disk.

Comment: **Saving time** for all of us that seek an answer based on the title: Choice 1. `sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk`. execute with: `usb-creator-gtk`. Operation: Pick the source image (downloaded iso) and destination usb and click "make startup disk". Choice 2 (alternative): `sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`. execute: `gnome-disks`. Operation:  Select the empty medium -> click on 3 dots -> "Restore image" -> select the downloaded iso -> click on "Start restoring". There is also a [related asnwer for ubuntu 19](https://askubuntu.com/a/1153429/622994).

Answer (score 0):

Your `brave-browser-release.list` file has a typo. Instead of `dep`, it should be `deb`. Fix this file, then update `apt`. The message should disappear.

To correct the file, do this:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Open the source file with the help of `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
   ```
3. Find `dep` and change it to `deb`
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit
5. Press <kbd>Y</kbd> when asked if you want to save the changes
6. Update `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

   Depending on how long this file has been broken, you may have a lot of pending updates to install.

As for the disk creator, it’s [hidden in a right-click action on Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/faq/usb-image/). Right click the `.iso` file and select “Open with Disk Image Writer”

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right.  Can you please also explain to me how to fix the file or point me to a resource that explains this? I am very much a newbie. Thank You!

Comment: I’ve updated the answer to show how you can correct the issue 